# How do I set application calculation back as to defined by user in Excel VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, calculation

I have a rather large workbook, and some users prefer to have automatic calculation on, while others prefer having it off.

Some macros that interact with the sheets are attatched to the workbook. To speed up my VBA code, I set

```
Application.Calculation = xlManual
```

In the beginning of each workbook.

My question is, how do I revert it back to the way it was in the end of macro?

Right now i'm using

```
Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
```

but that overrides the users choice. It's pretty annoying having to change it back to manual every time the macro has run. (Or the other way around, if leaving it at manual.)

Comment: Store the current setting in a global variable and restore the setting when you're done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Store the setting before starting, then restore when finished:

```
Sub calctest()
Dim calcsetting As Integer

    calcsetting = Application.Calculation
    ' Put code here
    Application.Calculation = calcsetting
End Sub
```

Comment: Great, can't believe I couldn't find that anywhere. Thank you!

Comment: @carol @johs32 `calcsetting` should be at least of type `Long` or better of type [`XlCalculation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/xlcalculation-enumeration-excel?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) (which also enables IntelliSense for this variable). You can see this if you do a `Debug.Print VarType(Application.Calculation)` it will be `3` which means `Long` (according to [VarType Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/vartype-function)). Best Practice: [Avoid Integer and always use Long](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26409520/3219613).

Comment: You may also want to use error handling so that the calculation is restored, even if your other code fails