# Speed up removal of all filter from all worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I am working in an Excel file. My code removes the filters from every worksheet.

The process is long and Excel freezes.

```vb
Sub Auto_Open()
    Dim xWs As Worksheet
    For Each Wks In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    On Error Resume Next
    If Wks.AutoFilterMode Then
        Wks.AutoFilterMode = False
    End If
    Next Wks
End Sub
```

*Edit:*

```vb
Sub Auto_Open()
    Application.Calculation = xlManual 'added this line which really sepd it up
    Dim xWs As Worksheet
    For Each Wks In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    On Error Resume Next
    If Wks.AutoFilterMode Then
        Wks.AutoFilterMode = False
    End If
    Next Wks
    Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
End Sub
```

Comment: Try [disabling automatic calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47545209/17017616) while doing the work:

Comment: So just add `Application.Calculation = xlManual` as first line of my Sub ?

Comment: @leosch is right , and activate automatic again at the end of your code

Comment: Yes. But you also must re-enable it when done. For test purpose you simply write `Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic` before the sub ends.

Comment: Could someone explain what this code really does, beside the obvious speed up?

Comment: [VBA – Turn Automatic Calculations Off (or On)](https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/on-off-calculations/)